# LINQ querying using an entity object not in the database - Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have an Entity Framework v5 model created from a database. The table Season has a corresponding entity called Season. [image: A screenshot of the Entity Framework EDMX showing the Season, Locations, Project, and Project_Group entities]I need to calculate the Season's minimum start date and maximum end date for each year for a Project_Group. I then need to be able to JOIN those yearly min/max Season values in other LINQ queries. To do so, I have created a SeasonLimits class in my Data Access Layer project. (A SeasonLimits table *does not* exist in the database.)

```
public partial class SeasonLimits : EntityObject
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public DateTime Min_Start_Date { get; set; }
    public int Min_Start_Date_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Max_End_Date { get; set; }
    public int Max_End_Date_ID { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<SeasonLimits> QuerySeasonLimits(MyEntities context, int project_Group_ID)
    {
        return context
            .Season
            .Where(s => s.Locations.Project.Project_Group.Any(pg => pg.Project_Group_ID == project_Group_ID))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Year)
            .Select(sl => new SeasonLimits
            {
                Year = sl.Key,
                Min_Start_Date = sl.Min(d => d.Start_Date),
                Min_Start_Date_ID = sl.Min(d => d.Start_Date_ID),
                Max_End_Date = sl.Max(d => d.End_Date),
                Max_End_Date_ID = sl.Max(d => d.End_Date_ID)
            });
    }
}

// MVC Project
var seasonHoursByYear =
    from d in context.AuxiliaryDateHours
    from sl in SeasonLimits.QuerySeasonLimits(context, pg.Project_Group_ID)
    where d.Date_ID >= sl.Min_Start_Date_ID
        && d.Date_ID < sl.Max_End_Date_ID
    group d by new
    {
        d.Year
    } into grp4
    orderby grp4.Key.Year
    select new
    {
        Year = grp4.Key.Year,
        HoursInYear = grp4.Count()
    };
```

In my MVC project, whenever I attempt to use the QuerySeasonLimits method in a LINQ query JOIN, I receive the message,

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyDAL.SeasonLimits]
>   QuerySeasonLimits(MyDAL.MyEntities, MyDAL.Project_Group)' method, and
>   this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Is this error being generated because SeasonLimits is not an entity that exists in the database? If this can't be done this way, is there another way to reference the logic so that it can be used in other LINQ queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is trying to translate your query to SQL and as there is no direct mapping between your method and the generated SQL you're getting the error.

First option would be not to use the method and instead write the contents of the method directly in the original query (I'm not sure at the moment if this would work, as I don't have a VS running). In the case this would work, you'll most likely end up with a very complicated SQL with a poor performance.

So here comes the second option: don't be afraid to use multiple queries to get what you need. Sometimes it also makes sense to send a simpler query to the DB and continue with modifications (aggregation, selection, ...) in the C# code. The query gets translated to SQL everytime you try to enumerate over it or if you use one of the `ToList`, `ToDictionary`, `ToArray`, `ToLookup` methods or if you're using a `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` calls (see the [LINQ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities) for the specifics).

One possible example that could fix your query (but most likely is not the best solution) is to start your query with:

```
var seasonHoursByYear =
    from d in context.AuxiliaryDateHours.ToList()
    [...]
```

and continue with all the rest. This minor change has fundamental impact:

1. by calling `ToList` the DB will be immediately queried and the whole 
   `AuxiliaryDateHours` table will be loaded into the application (this will be a performance problem if the table has too many rows)
2. a second query will be generated when calling your QuerySeasonLimits method (you could/should also include a `ToList` call for that)
3. the rest of the `seasonHoursByYear` query: `where`, grouping, ... will happen in memory

There are a couple of other points that might be unrelated at this point.

I haven't really investigated the intent of your code - as this could lead to further optimizations - even total reworks that could bring you more gains in the end...

Comment: I had success with your first option to eliminate the `SeasonLimits` object and the `QuerySeasonLimits` method, and to write the contents of the method directly in the original query. It will duplicate my code but at least it will execute.

Also, I attempted the `ToList` route but this query is the first part of a much larger query and Visual Studio quickly timed out when debugging as I expanded the query.

Answer (score 0):

I eliminated the SeasonLimits object and the QuerySeasonLimits method, and wrote the contents of the method directly in the original query.

```
// MVC Project
var seasonLimits =
    from s in context.Season
        .Where(s => s.Locations.Project.Project_Group.Any(pg => pg.Project_Group_ID == Project_Group_ID))
    group s by new
    {
        s.Year
    } into grp
    select new
    {
        grp.Key.Year,
        Min_Start_Date = grp.Min(x => x.Start_Date),
        Min_Start_Date_ID = grp.Min(x => x.Start_Date_ID),
        Max_End_Date = grp.Max(x => x.End_Date),
        Max_End_Date_ID = grp.Max(x => x.End_Date_ID)
    };

var seasonHoursByYear =
    from d in context.AuxiliaryDateHours
    from sl in seasonLimits
    where d.Date_ID >= sl.Min_Start_Date_ID
        && d.Date_ID < sl.Max_End_Date_ID
    group d by new
    {
        d.Year
    } into grp4
    orderby grp4.Key.Year
    select new
    {
        Year = grp4.Key.Year,
        HoursInYear = grp4.Count()
    };
```